# run shell command script in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to run the terminal command in dart?

I want to run this command using custom command on the terminal.

**custom command like this**

```
dart run build-dev(build-dev is a script file)
```

**full command in build-dev file**

```
rm pubspec.lock && flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter pub upgrade && flutter build apk --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

install this package.

`dart pub global activate flutter_scripts`

(if you use mac os, you should setup mac shell)

you can run the same command in Flutter by using the flutter run command. Here's an example of how you can do this:

Open the `pubspec.yaml` file in your Flutter project.

Add a new script to the scripts section of the file:

```
scripts:
  build-dev: flutter build apk --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart
```

Run the script using the flutter run command:

```
flutter_scripts run build-dev
```

This will execute the flutter build apk command with the specified arguments. You can then run this script anytime by using the flutter run build-dev command.

Answer (score -1):

You're asking for trouble running a `dart` script in a package that deletes the `lock` file and runs `clean` and `pub get`.

Also, `pub get` then `pub upgrade` is redundant. Just run `pub upgrade`.

Just make this a shell script (or batch file)!

Comment: no, I am asking is it possible to run a script in dart or not.